# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm fetching the data from API's but it causes too many re-renders.Needed help to control this behavior.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAdDetails(props.match.params && props.match.params.id);
    getAllReviews(props.match.params && props.match.params.id);
  
  }, [props.match.params.id, getAllReviews, fetchAdDetails]);
```

Comment: What are the functions `fetchAdDetails` and `getAllReviews`?

Comment: these are the actions

Comment: fetched data from the API's on the basis of id (props.match.params.id)

Comment: By many re-renders you mean react error: "maximum update depth exceeded"?

Comment: @АлексейМартинкевич Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchAdDetails(props.match.params && props.match.params.id);
    getAllReviews(props.match.params && props.match.params.id);
  
  }, []);
```

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: not working still the same re-renders error.

Comment: I might be wrong but if you still face the same problem then the useEffect is not your problem. Is there maybe any other useEffects that might run in this component? Or maybe data that you change in your parent component that could lead to your issue?